# Upgrading setuptools on Mountain Lion following Python upgrade

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, easy-install

I am running Mountain Lion with Python 2.7.2 installed. In the past, I've installed virtualenv using pip install and all has worked well. However, I had some problems running several packages and so decided to upgrade Python (2.7.8) using the .dmg at python.org.

The installation installed a version of Python in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework and I ran the Update Shell Profile.command to make this the default Python. Now when I enter 'python' at the terminal prompt, 2.7.8 starts up so all's well, so far.

In an admin account, I then upgraded setuptools using:

```
> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python
```

This installed easy_install at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install (i.e. with the new default Python 2.7.8 installation). This seemed to install OK but when tried to install pip:

```
> sudo easy_install pip
```

it failed with error saying:

```
ImportError: cannot import name ContextualZipFile
```

I thought perhaps there was a different version of easy_install that was trying to run but if I explicitly run the new version of easy_install it gives the same error message:

Any suggestions why this should be happening? Some reports suggest it may be a bug introduced during an update to setuptools (but that was several updates ago and was supposed to have been fixed - but it could have been broken again, I suppose). Is there any way to install a previous version?

Comment: Too late for you, but I recommend something like Macports http://www.macports.org/ or Homebrew http://brew.sh/ for installing multiple Python versions (they don't mess with system paths) - they are less error prone and you can nuke the whole installation and start from the scratch in the case of error

Comment: Thanks of the comment. Generally I use Fink to update such things. I had used it in this case but was subsequently have problems with another Python package. That is why I went down the 'official' route of using the .dmg from the Python site. But, as it turns out, it didn't help and introduced this new problem.

Comment: I'll chime in to second using Homebrew.  It can and will clean up after itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried installing pip as per http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: It's not my question, I guess I can't do that.

Comment: Thanks - that sorted it for me! Since got other issues but that's another story...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Mountain Lion. I'm using Mavericks (10.9.4).

I just tried your steps and did not have the same error. I don't want to post the long response to comment, so here I am. Hope this helps you a little.

First, I downloaded `python-2.7.8-macosx10.6.dmg` from download page of [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

After installing, I checked that I'm now using this version of python

```
LongQuanJian:~ joysword$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

LongQuanJian:~ joysword$ python
Python 2.7.8 (v2.7.8:ee879c0ffa11, Jun 29 2014, 21:07:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Then I tried to run the commends you provided and it succeeded. The log is at:

https://gist.github.com/joysword/2fe24ae34c573e205144

Note that the second commend

> sudo easy_install pip

is at line 248.

Comment: Thanks very much for responding. I'm not at the right computer at the moment but I'll take a look at the log you posted when I get back.